# Codeigniter - Query returns 1 row even though there is no data to match

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is my controller

```
public function login() {
    $this->load->model('admin_model');

    $access = $this->admin_model->check_login();
    $data['content'] = 'content/home';
    $data['title'] = 'Admin Panel Login';

    if($access) {
        $data= array(
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'is_logged_in' => true
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        redirect('admin/index/dashboard');
    } else {
        $this->index($page = 'home', $msg = 'failure');
}
```

Here is my model

```
public function check_login() {
    $this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('email'));
    $this->db->where('password', $this->input->post('password'));
    $query = $this->db->get('customers');

    return (bool) $query->num_rows;
}
```

So what I have been working on is a function in my Admin constructor that will ensure that users cannot access any page until they are logged in. The problem is that when I go to admin/login, it is setting is_logged_in to true, even though the check_login function should be returning as false. It's saying that it is finding a row, even though there is only 1 row in my DB right now which it shouldn't be matching.

I'm new to CI, so please be gentle. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`num_rows()` is a method (not a property) and should be used more like this:

```
return $query->num_rows() > 0;
```

Comment: Even after adjusting my code, it's not working. The query it is doing is: 

SELECT *
FROM (`customers`)
WHERE `email` =  0
AND `password` =  0 

and it's returning check_login() as true. (0 and 0 is what it's posting by default) Maybe I have it organized incorrectly?

Comment: Can you run that query directly against your database (outside of CI) and see what's returned?

Comment: Sure. Here is the output: "Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 0.0004 sec)". I just can't seem to figure out why $access is coming back as true.

Comment: Reread what you just posted :) Namely, the `1 total` part. It sounds like your query is indeed returning a single record.

Comment: Yes, this is the message being output by PHPMyAdmin. I assumed it was referring to the single record in my database. "Rows 0 - 0" would mean there are no rows that match the query, out of 1 row total.

Comment: phpMyAdmin will display `MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).` when no rows are returned. I'm positive your query is returning a single row. Consider that the rows returned are zero-based - i.e. the first record returned is row 0.

Comment: I edited the query to check if they were "" instead of 0, and it didn't return anything at all. I misunderstood how PHPMyAdmin was working. So the issue is that it's matching the zeros to the values in my database which makes no sense at all.

Comment: May I suggest not allowing a form submission if `email` and `password` values don't exist? Let me know if you'd like to move this discussion to chat.

Comment: I've determined that the problem is that CodeIgniter is setting email and password to 0 in the query, which in PHPMyAdmin is being determined as something odd.. like "no value", so it grabs all of the records in my db. So I'm going to add validation that will not allow the model function to be used unless there are values set, like you said. I see that there is a lot of reorganization that is needed. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to upvote my answer if it was helpful, and best of luck on your project.

Answer (score 1):

An expansion on Colin's answer:

```
public function check_login() {
    $this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('email'));
    $this->db->where('password', $this->input->post('password'));
    $query = $this->db->get('customers');

    if ($query->num_rows()>0) {
      return TRUE;
    } else {
      return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried this as well. The problem isn't that I'm coding my conditional statements incorrectly, it's that it is returning 1 row, even though it should not be. When I go directly to admin/login, it acts as if I submitted data (which would be 0 and 0), and so it returns true, which it should not be.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see the point in your model.

A model can't (or even if it can, shouldn't) get the variables from the view. It should come via controller.

Are you sure, the post variables are appearing in the model?

Better solution. Catch the post variables in controller.

In the model, create functions with parameters.

Then in the controller, retrieve it like this.

```
$data['bla'] = $this->admin_model->method_name($this->input->post('blabla'));
```

this will prevent all these confusions.

Comment: Yes, I had it arranged that way before. Both work the same, but I'll adjust it again.